# Azure AD B2C custom attribute is showing empty

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, token, azure-ad-b2c

I have created custom attribute name Organization using userflow in Azure AD B2C Tenant, but while fetching token details it's showing empty.

I added same user attribute in Sign up process but same.

Any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to get the custom attribute token details**

Created one Applications in Azure AD B2C Tenant

**AzurePortal>Azure AD B2C> App registrations>New Registration**

[image]

Created User Attribute with Name **Oraganization Name**

**AzurePortal>Azure AD B2C> User attributes>Add**

[image]

Created user flow with custom attribute like below

**AzurePortal>Azure AD B2C> User flows>New user Flow>Signup and Sign in>Recommended**

Select the custom attribute while creating signin and Signup user flow like below

[image]

Make sure select your application while testing the user flow

[image]

Finally, i got the output with custom attribute Name

[image]